# asyncTask onProgressUpdate does not work at 2nd invoking

Tags: android, android-asynctask, dialog

im using asyncTask to showing a download progress , my download will be done by a library named "file-downloader" in my main activity.
it's github page is "https://github.com/wlfcolin/file-downloader"

my custom dialog shows when i click to my specified button , and download task and progressBar starts when i press download button in this custom dialog
all thing is ok and progressBar works fine.

but when i dismiss this dialog and another time i invoke this dialog the progressBar does not work !
i save download status in database using the fileDownloader library listeners and anothe time i invoke custom dialog it read from database
and detect downloadProgress is currently running but we see no changing in custom dialog's progressBar , what is the problem ?

activity code

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    /*
    /
    / some variables
    /
    */

    public static int downloadedFile2SizePercent = 0 ; // downloaded file percent 
    public static int downloadingFileStatus = 0;  // downloading status 
    Button myBtn ;
    DownloadDialog dd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    myBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button22);
    myBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dd = new DownloadDialog(mContext,1);
            dd.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            dd.show();
        }
    });

    /*
    / downloadingFileStatus value manages here by file downloader listeners correctly and saves as static variable and also in database
    / downloadedFile2SizePercent value manages here by file downloader listeners correctly and saves as static variable
    /
    */

    }


}
```

DownloadDialog Class

```
    public class DownloadDialog extends Dialog implements View.OnClickListener{

public Context c;
public Button download, delete;
private ProgressBar pb;
ProgressTask progressTask;
private int downloadStatus;
private String downloadLink;
private int downloadID

public DownloadDialog(Context a, int downloadId) {
    super(a);
    this.c = a;
    this.downloadId = downloadId
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.download_dialog);
    download = (Button) findViewById(R.id.downloaddialot_downloadbtn);
    delete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.downloaddialot_deletebtn);
    download.setOnClickListener(this);
    delete.setOnClickListener(this);

    pb = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    pb.setMax(100);
    pb.setProgress(0);

    //database is opend at mainActivity it's static
    downloadStatus=Integer.parseInt(MainActivity.prDb.intSearch(downloadId));// detects download status --> 0 is "notDownloadedYet" and
    // 1 is "downloading" and 2 is "downloaded"
    downloadLink=  MainActivity.puDb.intSearch(downloadId);//detects download link

    progressTask = new ProgressTask();


    if(downloadStatus==1){
            pb.setProgress(MainActivity.downloadedFile2SizePercent);//this code line works every 2nd and after dialog invoking
            progressTask.execute(true);
            Toast.makeText(c,"test task progress for 2nd started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//this code line works every 2nd and afterdialog invoking
    }

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.downloaddialot_downloadbtn:
                    FileDownloader.start(downloadLink); // download task starts here
                    progressTask.execute(true);
                    Toast.makeText(c,"download task progress for 1nd started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        case R.id.downloaddialot_deletebtn:
            if(downloadStatus==2){
                // delete codes
            }
            break;
    }
}


public  class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask<Boolean, Integer, Boolean> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Boolean... params) {

        while (MainActivity.downloadedFile2SizePercent!=100){
              publishProgress(MainActivity.downloadedFile2SizePercent);
        }
        if(MainActivity.downloadedFile2SizePercent==100){
            publishProgress(MainActivity.downloadedFile2SizePercent);
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        pb.setProgress(values[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
        super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
        downloadStatus=2; //also saves in database by download listeners in mainActivity
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The progress bar just like any other UI element can only be managed or updated from the main UI thread.

It is the time consuming task the part that should be run in a AsyncTask, then this task can save the progress status in a volatile variable and then the UI thread can periodically update the progress bar reading the volatile variable, for example using a timer.

Comment: do u say the progressbar cant be managed by asynctask that is made in custom dialog ? so i said for firs dialog invoking it works !

Comment: I don't really understand well your code. it seems a bad design from OOP view. You should avoid the use of static. It is supposed that a Dialog should show an information and nothing else and in your code it seems that the dialog does the main part.

Answer (score 0):

You can read all about `AsyncTask` here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

But here's my quick example/tutorial:

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // prepare your UI for the background task beginning
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // do some long-running task...

        // you can do partial updates like:
        publishProgress(25);
        /* more hard work */
        publishProgress(50);
        /* even more hard work */
        publishProgress(75);

        // and when you're done...
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        // update your UI with the current progress (values[0])
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        // update your UI now that it's done
    }
}
```

The key concept to understand regarding `AsyncTask` is that every method **except** `doInBackground()` is executed on the UI thread (the main thread). That means you are free to update your UI from these calls.

`doInBackground()`, however, is executed on a different thread. That means you can do expensive work here without slowing down your app's user interface.

Of course, all the hard work you're doing on that background thread needs to make its way to the UI thread somehow (so that you can use it). That's what `publishProgress()` and the `return` statement of `doInBackground()` are for. When you call `publishProgress(someValue)`, the system will invoke `onProgressUpdate(someValue)` for you. When you `return someValue`, the system will invoke `onPostExecute(someValue)` for you.